# jquery onclick event doesn't work for link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i have a script on top of my jsp page just before `</head>`. everything works as expected except onclick event for `<a>`. this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'paging',
    type: 'GET'
  }).success(function (data) {
    $('#pagination').empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, user) {
      $('#pagination').append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr({
          'onclick': 'GoToProfile(' + user.username + ')'
           }).text(user.username)))
        .append($('<td>').text(user.email)))
      });
    
      $("#sales").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
      });
   });
});
    
function GoToProfile(user) {
  window.location.href = "/profile/" + user;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

why `GoToProfile` function doesn't work, when i click on a username?. i've put it in different positions, inside `$(document).ready`,outside and etc ,but didn't work.

Comment: You're probably getting syntax errors in the browser console.

Comment: After fixing your syntax errors, change: `.attr({
          'onclick': 'GoToProfile(' + user.username + ')'
    }` to: `.on('click', function(){GoToProfile(ser.username);})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Scott Marcus said:

```
attr({'onclick': 'GoToProfile(' + user.username + ')'})
```

should change to

```
on('click', function(){GoToProfile(user.username)})
```

the confusing point is that i've used exactly the same syntax for my links in other places of project and they worked perfectly well. i just don't know why it didn't work here!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this approach, although the rest of the code has not been written really well. I did not test it, but it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function GoToProfile(user) {
    window.location.href = "/profile/" + user;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'paging',
    type: 'GET'
  }).success(function (data) {
    $('#pagination').empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, user) {
      $('#pagination').append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>').append($(`<a data-username="${user.username}">`).text(user.username)))
        .append($('<td>').text(user.email)))
      });

      $("#sales").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
      });
   });
  $("#pagination").on("click", "a", function(){
    const $this = $(this);
    GoToProfile($this.attr(data-username));
  });
});
```